# Is this pale sloppy guy from a movie?

Tags: character-identification

[image: White guy]

I am looking for this guy.

Is this a character of some movie, or a model of some gfx studio?
Would like to have some better quality pictures of him.

Thanks folks

Comment: That looks like an alien, so it would probably be sci-if.

Comment: Right click -> "Search Google for this image"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### It's a sculpture by the surrealist sculptor [Matthew J Levin](https://matthewjlevin.com/).

On his portfolio [here](https://matthewjlevin.com/portfolio/), it's the middle picture in the 15th row; a direct link to this picture is [here](https://matthewjlevin.com/portfolio/img_3215w/):

[image: sculpture]

It's also been turned into an internet meme, and can be found at [We Know Memes](https://weknowmemes.com/2013/12/doing-the-dishes-and-a-piece-of-food-touches-your-hand/) as follows:

[image: same image with caption "doing the dishes and a piece of food touches your hand"]

Comment: Thanks ... That is the one.

But I guess it has never had an appereance in any movie ... I could imagine this to be a very funny character.